# Converting shape layer with POLYGON and MULTIPOLYGON to POINT geometry

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to convert shape file to `POINT` geometry using QGIS 3.10.5.

Here is info of my shape file:

[image]

Here are my conversion settings:

[image]

Error that I get:

> Export to vector file failed. Error: Feature write errors: Feature
> creation error (OGR error: Attempt to write non-multipoint
> (MULTIPOLYGON) geometry to multipoint shapefile.)

I can successfully load data in MSSQL server which is recognizing all shapes nicely so shape file is OK.
I need to convert to POINT geometry to work with visualizations in Tableau.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My actual problem was that I had MULTIPOLYGONS which Tableau doesn't support. Tableau do support POLYGONS.

Answer (score 1):

Run Centroids first:

From:

Vector> Geometry Tools> Centroids..

This will generate a point per feature, in the center of the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Multipart to singleparts* tool to convert your multi polygons in single polygons
then *Centroid* to make a point for each feature as suggested by HeikkiVesanto
and save as a point shapefile like you tried before.